# BOX JAVA SDK: EventLog.getEnterpriseEvents returns error

Tags: java, box

Calling EventLog.getEnterpriseEvents
with timeframe of (now - 2hrs) until (now) returns error 400 (bad_request):

```
created_before is beyond one year in the past, API only supports time range starting from one year in the past from now
```

I'm using the Java SDK and am autenticated properly (w/ private key, JWT), with all the possible permissions granted.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with the request made via the SDK,

the issue is in the underlying REST API - it has a bug where date formats with +UTC throw an error (where -UTC is just fine).
The SDK uses [DateFormat class to stringify the Date object](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/box/sdk/BoxDateFormat.java), and I'm located at a zone which is at UTC+200.

This is very strange that this wasn't picked up as this effects half of the planet users who will attempt to use this REST API (and SDK).

As workaround, I forked the SDK and formatting using normalized UTC date, so I don't get +UTC.

i.e.

```
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

Also, I submitted a bug to Box engineers.